# Print all input from web page

Tags: python, mechanize

I tried to create a small autoposter script. I need to find and print all input from a webpage. I'm trying to use the `mechanize` library.

I wrote this script:

```
import urllib  
import cookielib  
import mechanize  

url = "https://www.sito.com/page.html"  

cookie = cookielib.CookieJar()  
browser = mechanize.Browser()  

browser.set_cookiejar(cookie)  
browser.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)  

browser.open(url)  

for f  in browser.forms():  
    print f.name
```

How can I print all input from web page with `mechanize` or possibly another library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use `urllib2` + `BeautifulSoup`:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://sito.com/SitoContact.htm"  # change to whatever your url is

page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

for i in soup.find_all('input'):
    print i
```

FYI, I couldn't access the page you've provided due to ssl error, that's why the example is using another URL.

Note, in case you need to fill the form or make some actions with inputs, you will need `mechanize` or similar tools. But, anyway, you may continue to use `BeautifulSoup` for parsing the html. Also, take a look at [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) project.

Comment: how can i print only the name of the input ?

Comment: @kingcope `i.attrs['name']`.